# remount, turn off SElinux, all fails even though I am root

Tags: rooting, mount, system, selinux

I have a device which is never hacked into before, mostly as nobody has it, it is a android tv box. I have temp root using the dirty cow exploit, and tried to remount system using the mount command. it says permission denied even tho I am root. so can anybody guide me to get system remounted with rw permissions?

heres some of the shell:

```
$ adb shell
shell@ganesa:/ $ /data/local/tmp/dcow /data/local/tmp/run-as /system/bin/run-a>
dcow /data/local/tmp/run-as /system/bin/run-as
warning: new file size (9804) and destination file size (17920) differ
[*] size 17920[*] mmap 0xb6d64000[*] currently 0xb6d64000=464c457f[*] using /proc/self/mem method[*] madvise = 0xb6d64000 17920[*] madvise = 0 17449[*] /proc/self/mem 10931200 610[*] exploited 0 0xb6d64000=464c457f
shell@ganesa:/ $ /system/bin/run-as
uid /system/bin/run-as 2000
uid 0
0 u:r:runas:s0
context 0 u:r:shell:s0
shell@ganesa:/ # Hehehe
/system/bin/sh: Hehehe: not found
127|shell@ganesa:/ # which touch
/system/bin/touch
shell@ganesa:/ # touch Hi.txt
touch: 'Hi.txt': Read-only file system
1|shell@ganesa:/ # mount -o rw,remount /system
mount: Permission denied
255|shell@ganesa:/ # ls -ladZ sys
sys/    system/
255|shell@ganesa:/ # ls -ladZ system
drwxr-xr-x root     root              u:object_r:system_file:s0 system
shell@ganesa:/ # setenforce 0
setenforce: Couldn't set enforcing status to '0': Permission denied
1|shell@ganesa:/ # sestatus
/system/bin/sh: sestatus: not found
127|shell@ganesa:/ # cat
^C
130|shell@ganesa:/ #
130|shell@ganesa:/ #
130|shell@ganesa:/ #
130|shell@ganesa:/ #
130|shell@ganesa:/ #
130|shell@ganesa:/ # cat /etc/selinux/config
/system/bin/sh: cat: /etc/selinux/config: No such file or directory
1|shell@ganesa:/ # cd etc
shell@ganesa:/etc # ls
18p
NOTICE.html.gz
audio_effects.conf
audio_policy.conf
bluetooth
clatd.conf
dhcpcd
event-log-tags
fallback_fonts.xml
fonts.xml
gps.conf
hosts
media_codecs.xml
media_codecs_google_audio.xml
media_codecs_google_tv.xml
media_codecs_google_video.xml
media_codecs_performance.xml
media_profiles.xml
mkshrc
permissions
ppp
preloaded-classes
recovery-resource.dat
security
sysconfig
system_fonts.xml
wifi
shell@ganesa:/etc # touch lol
touch: 'lol': Read-only file system
1|shell@ganesa:/etc # mount -o rw,remount /
mount: Permission denied
255|shell@ganesa:/etc # su mount -o rw,remount /
/system/bin/sh: su: not found
127|shell@ganesa:/etc # sudo mount -o rw,remount /
/system/bin/sh: sudo: not found
127|shell@ganesa:/etc #
127|shell@ganesa:/etc #
```

I think it is SELinux, but even if I try to disable it I get permission denied. remember there is no access to recovery mode, nor bootloader nor usb adb. I have tried everything on the web

Thanks!

Comment: On Android, root means: 1) UID 0, and 2) all Linux capabilies, and 3) a fully permissive SELinux context. I'm sure one of the latter two conditions aren't met in your case. For details see my answers to previous questions on this topic.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do on /system once you have root? looks like a script kiddie with no plan at all. even if you manage to get root access you will most likely trigger dm-verity and permanently brick! i recommend to careful read all warnings on this bootless root method [magisk-boot.zip](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3922213&page=100) modern root methods do not touch /system [systemless-root](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/systemless-root/info)

Comment: @IrfanLatif Can you link it?

Comment: @alecxs lol this is an android tv box with no bootloader/recovery access, I am trying to get su installed. Nobody has ever rooted, if it gets bricked it goes onto the manufacturer, it is already mostly dead anyway. the quality of this box is shit. so they ditched it and made a new one.

Comment: @alecxs how to check dm-verity

Comment: implementation differs and i am not aware of universal method to check. you can try `adb disable-verity` but it's pointless

Comment: @alecxs aight, it has verity on, so can you help me get magisk or stuff gt installed in it?

Comment: @alecxs the device is armeabi-7, unupported by mtk-su

Comment: I could only get partial root through dirtycow

Comment: @alecxs Whats your uname on xda?